# Defining a property on mongo schema referencing another schema plus extra fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to define a mongo Schema using mongoose. I need to create an 'Event Schema' in which users are referenced. So I am populating the 'users' field with the referenced ObjectId of the user Schema. However I also need to add some extra fields on that user property which are specific to the event. So something like as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EventSchema = new Schema({

    name: String,
    date: Date,
    users: [{
        profile: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        RankNumber: Number,
        bibNumber: Number 
    }],
    published: Boolean

});

mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

However this doesn't work. I am not sure the best way to do what I am trying to achieve.

So if I have a constructor function such as:

```
function User(bib, rank, profile) {
    this.bib = bib;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.profile = profile;
}
```

and then I call that constructor and pass in a user id as the profile property, MongoDB will create a new id field. I get a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "name": "Event name",
    "_id: "mongoid",
    "users": [
        {
            "bibNumber": "278",
            "rankNumber": "21",
            "profile": "users mongo _id number",
            "_id": "a new mongo _id"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to populate the profile field. But the following won't work:

Event.find().populate('users').exec(function (err, events) {....

Comment: "This doesn't work". Please precise

Comment: I have edited the question. See above.

Comment: Can you try `populate('users.profile')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use, as I said in the comments:

```
Event.find(...).populate('users.profile').exec(...);
```